# Obtain the value from textbox inside of a DataTemplate (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, datatemplate

I´ve just created a datatemplate for a ListBox like that:

```
 <ListBox Height="150" MinHeight="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="myListBox"           
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Multiple" Margin="0,18,0,0">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <CheckBox Name="cbLista" Width="100"  Content="{Binding Path=Nom_estudio}"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                  Checked="cbLista_Checked" />
                                            <TextBox Name="txbCantidad" Width="100" Margin="0,0,0,5" TextChanged="txbCantidad_TextChanged" />
                                        </StackPanel>

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
```

And now I can get every object selected in the checkbox, but how can I obtain the text property for the texbox asociated for every checkbox ?

Comment: You could use a binding, e.g. `Text="{Binding Cantidad}"`. Of course, this requires that you create a `Cantidad` property on the same object that has the `Nom_estudio` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the "Text" property of the TextBox to some property (say `MyTextProperty`) on your data object. Then when you get the "SelectedItems" list, you just access this property.

ie:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}" ... />
```

Comment: @nit, easy to when its a simple question, I almost beat out the first comment ;) Your answer is just as good though, and will get an upvote from me.

Answer (score 1):

Create on more property in your class which has `Nom_estudio` and `IsChecked` properties. Then bind that property to `TextBox.Text` property

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Name="cbLista" Width="100"  Content="{Binding Path=Nom_estudio}"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                              Checked="cbLista_Checked" />
                 <TextBox Name="txbCantidad" Text="{Binding MYTEXTPROPERTY}" Width="100" Margin="0,0,0,5" TextChanged="txbCantidad_TextChanged" />
                                    </StackPanel>
```